# PHP - Illegal offset type, after is_array and is_object

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.1, laravel-5

I have this method:

```
public function setVariable($variable, $value = null)
{
    $variables = json_decode($this->variables);

    if(is_array($variable) || is_object($variable))
        foreach($variable as $key => $value)
            if(in_array($key, $this->variableNames))
                $variables[$key] = $value;
    else
        $variables[$variable] = $value;

    $this->variables = json_encode($variables);
    $this->save();
}
```

But, if I call the method like this:

```
setVariable(['test' => 'test', 'bla' => 'bla'])
```

It return this error:

```
ErrorException in User.php line 60:
Illegal offset type
```

Line 60 is this line:

```
$variables[$variable] = $value;
```

But, why it return the error?
I check if $variable is array or object,
But it continues return this error. Why?

Comment: Because you and php consider `else` differently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code

```
if(is_array($variable) || is_object($variable))
    foreach($variable as $key => $value)
        if(in_array($key, $this->variableNames))
            $variables[$key] = $value;
else
    $variables[$variable] = $value;
```

for php is the same as:

```
if(is_array($variable) || is_object($variable)) {
    foreach($variable as $key => $value) {
        if(in_array($key, $this->variableNames))
            $variables[$key] = $value;
        else
            $variables[$variable] = $value;
    }
}
```

See the difference? That's why use `{}` to show what you **really** need:

```
if (is_array($variable) || is_object($variable)) {
    foreach($variable as $key => $value) {
        if(in_array($key, $this->variableNames)) {
            $variables[$key] = $value;
        }
    }
} else {
    $variables[$variable] = $value;
}
```

Also be aware (thanks to @FirstOne) that `foreach` over `stdClass object` (when `$variable` is object) is invalid operation and will raise error.

Comment: This is bugging me. Can you check [my comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38084565/php-illegal-offset-type-after-is-array-and-is-object#comment63605497_38084565)? I mean, wouldn't this code give _E\_ERROR : type 1 -- Cannot use object of type stdClass as array_?

Comment: I mean - i __will__ mention.

Comment: To enrich the answer, take a look at this example: [**https://3v4l.org/1dZLv**](https://3v4l.org/1dZLv). The problem is related to the part where the op tried to change the value (like `$variables[$key] =..`). To use it like that, the [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) call should include `true` as second argument. So `$variables = json_decode($this->variables, true);`.